# If I query from V$SQL view, does it include SQL that are still running and not yet finished?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm running a query below in an oracle db.

```
SELECT program_id, program_line#, sql_text
FROM V$SQL VS ,
     ALL_USERS AU
WHERE (executions >= 1)
  AND (parsing_user_id != 0)
  AND (AU.user_id(+) = VS.parsing_user_id)
  AND UPPER(AU.USERNAME)  IN (UPPER('CARGO'))
ORDER BY last_active_time DESC;
```

I just wanted to ask if the result returned by this query includes sql that are still running or query that has timeout or cancelled by the user?

Comment: Offtopic: `... FROM V$SQL VS ,
     ALL_USERS AU ... AND (AU.user_id(+) = VS.parsing_user_id)` i would suggest making the switch to explicit JOIN syntax instead off using ANSI/ISO  SQL comma join syntax and mixing it with Oracles only `(+)` syntax to make it possible to LEFT or RIGHT join..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `V$SQL` shows information about queries that are still running. From [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-2B9340D7-4AA8-4894-94C0-D5990F67BE75.htm#REFRN30246):

> `V$SQL` lists statistics on shared SQL areas without the GROUP BY clause
>   and contains one row for each child of the original SQL text entered.
>   Statistics displayed in `V$SQL` are normally updated at the end of query
>   execution. However, for long running queries, they are updated every 5
>   seconds. This makes it easy to see the impact of long running SQL
>   statements while they are still in progress.

As for the second part of your question, the answer is: It Depends. The length of time a query stays in the cache (where `V$SQL` gathers information,) depends on the size of your cache and the amount of unique/distinct queries that are running at any given time. If the same type of queries are frequently ran in the database (i.e. they are cached,) old queries will remain in the `V$SQL` view for a longer period of time than in databases where there are many distinct queries being executed (assuming everything else is the same.) Distinct queries that aren't already stored in the cache are added to the cache library, pushing older/timed out queries out of the cache. If you want to configure the amount of time queries spend in cache, you will have to configure the size of the shared pool. I would recommend reading up on the Library Cache at https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_shared_pool.htm#TGDBA560